# ALSA Sample Rate drift vs monotonic clock

Tags: clock, alsa

I have an application that samples audio at 8Khz using ALSA. This is set via snd_pcm_hw_params() and can be confirmed by looking at /proc:

```
cat /proc/asound/card1/pcm0c/sub0/hw_params
access: MMAP_INTERLEAVED
format: S32_LE
subformat: STD
channels: 12
rate: 8000 (8000/1)
period_size: 400
buffer_size: 1200
```

The count of samples read over time is effectively a monotonic clock.
If I compare the number of samples read with the system monotonic clock I note there is a drift over time. The sample clock appears to lose 1s roughly every 5 hours relative to the monotonic clock.
I have code to compensate for this at the application level (i.e. to correctly map sample counts to wall clock times) but I am wondering if we can or why we can't do better at a lower level?

Answer (score 0):

Both clocks are based on oscillators of some kind which may have some small error. So likely we are sampling at 7999.5Khz rather than 8Khz and the error builds up over time. Equally the system clock may have some small error in it.

The system clocks are corrected periodically by NTP so perhaps can permit more error but even so this deviation seems much larger than I would intuitively effect.
However, see for example http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-sw-clocks-quality.htm

In theory NTP can generate a drift file which you could use to see the drift rate of your system clock.

I would have thought that knowing that there is some small error. Something would try to autocorrect itself either by swapping between two differently wrong sample rates e.g. 8000.5Khz & 7999.5Khz or dropping the occasional sample. In fact I thought this kind of thing was done at the hardware or firmware level in order to stabilize the average frequency given a [crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator) with a known error.
Also I would have thought quartz crystals are put in circuits these days with at least temperature compensation.